# Fastest way to count duplicate integers in two distinct sections of an array

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

In this snippet of Python code,

`fun` iterates through the array `arr` and counts the number of identical integers in two array sections for every section pair. (It simulates a matrix.) This makes `n*(n-1)/2*m` comparisons in total, giving a time complexity of `O(n^2)`.

Are there programming solutions or ways of reframing this problem that would yield equivalent results but have reduced time complexity?

```
# n > 500000, 0 < i < n, m = 100
# dim(arr) = n*m, 0 < arr[x] < 4294967311

arr = mp.RawArray(ctypes.c_uint, n*m)

def fun(i):
    for j in range(i-1,0,-1):
        count = 0
        for k in range(0,m):
            count += (arr[i*m+k] == arr[j*m+k])
        if count/m > 0.7:
            return (i,j)
    return ()
```

- `arr` is a shared memory array, therefore it's best kept read-only for simplicity and performance reasons.
- `arr` is implemented as a 1D RawArray from `multiprocessing`. The reason for this it has by far the fastest performance according to my tests. Using a `numpy` 2D array, for example, like this:

  ```
  arr = np.ctypeslib.as_array(mp.RawArray(ctypes.c_uint, n*m)).reshape(n,m)
  ```

  would provide vectorization capabilities, but increases the total runtime by an order of magnitude - 250s vs. 30s for n = 1500, which amounts to **733%**.

Comment: Let's see -- you want to keep the original list intact and use minuscule additional memory.  You also want to solve some abstract counting problem described only in four indices with no associated semantics ...

Comment: ... as the posting guidelines say, please make it easy for people to help you.  Describe the problem you're trying to solve in practical terms.  From the interplay of loops here, I expect there's a much easier way to do this with the vectorization of numpy, but I'm not going to cross my eyes enough to suss out what your goal might be.

Comment: @ppw0: somewhat better.  Still not quite up to standard, since the code doesn't run as given.

Comment: You keep referring to this as an array, but your code doesn't include anything with an array type.  Is this really an array, or nested lists?  Your lack of a full example leaves it ambiguous.

Comment: @Prune It's declared as a RawArray, I added that now. But since it's 1D, without copying the array sections for each count, I can't "pull out" a vector of counts for every pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after fiddling around some more, I was able to cut down the running time greatly with help from NumPy's vectorization and Numba's JIT compiler. Going back to the original code:

```
arr = mp.RawArray(ctypes.c_uint, n*m)

def fun(i):
    for j in range(i-1,0,-1):
        count = 0
        for k in range(0,m):
            count += (arr[i*m+k] == arr[j*m+k])
        if count/m > 0.7:
            return (i,j)
return ()
```

We can leave out the bottom `return` statement as well as dismiss the idea of using `count` entirely, leaving us with:

```
def fun(i):
    for j in range(i-1,0,-1):
        if sum(arr[i*m+k] == arr[j*m+k] for k in range(m)) > 0.7*m:
            return (i,j)
```

Then, we change the array `arr` to a NumPy format:

```
np_arr = np.frombuffer(arr,dtype='int32').reshape(m,n)
```

The important thing to note here is that we do not use a NumPy array as a shared memory array to be *written* from multiple processes, avoiding the overhead pitfall.

Finally, we apply Numba's decorator and rewrite the `sum` function in vector form so that it works with the new array:

```
import numba as nb
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def fun(i):
    for j in range(i-1, 0, -1):
        if np.sum(np_arr[i] == np_arr[j]) > 0.7*m:
            return (i,j)
```

This reduced the running time to **7.9s**, which is definitely a victory for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't change the array characteristics at all, I think you're stuck with **O(n^2)**.  `numpy` would gain some vectorization, but would change the access for others sharing the array.  Start with the innermost operation:

```
    for k in range(0,m):
        count += (arr[i][k] == arr[j][k])
```

Change this to a one-line assignment:

```
    count = sum(arr[i][k] == arr[j][k] for k in range(m))
```

Now, if this is *truly* an array, rather than a list of lists, use the array package's vectorization to simplify the loops, one at a time:

```
    count = sum(arr[i] == arr[j])   # results in a vector of counts
```

You can now return the `j` indices where `count[j] / m > 0.7`.  Note that there's no real need to return `i` for each one: it's constant within the function, and the calling program already has the value.  Your array package likely has a pair of vectorized indexing operations that can return those indices.  If you're using `numpy`, those are easy enough to look up on this site.

Comment: Is it advisable to try C-extensions next?

Comment: I would think so.  I don't work there, myself -- if the job requires that much optimization, we leave interpreters behind and go to a fully-compiled language.